# Programmatically set numeric fivestar value in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fivestar

I have a Drupal 7 site and am using fivestar on one content type. Some nodes of that content type are created using a Feed Importer with xpath parser (the rest are created in the more traditional /node/add drupal way). For these imported feeds, I have an incoming field that contains a numeric rating value (0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100), which I would like add to my fivestar field so that these ratings can be tracked and displayed in a manner consistent with the drupal-created nodes.

My problem is that my Fivestar field (field_rating) does not appear as a target for the xpath parser import. Is there a way to pull this rating, or alternatively can someone point me to a way to programmatically set this Fivestar field value?

UPDATE:
I've found _fivestar_cast_vote, but am having trouble getting it to take for the field I'm trying to use, which is "rated when editing". I can use _fivestar_cast_vote for a different fivestar field on the same node which is "Rated when viewing", so I feel like I have the syntax right. For the "rated when editing" field, I'm using the uid of the user that the content is assigned to upon import...For testing, I'm doing this in the node--*.tpl.php file, and will likely move to a cron hook if I can get it to work...

Comment: If I recall correctly, you simply use an INT value between 0-100.  Use something like DD() or DPM() to find where to store it though.  It's stored somewhere like $field_five_star_whatever[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find this one but it goes like this for creating the fivestar value programatically

$node->field_name_of_your_field[$node->language][0]['rating'] = 20;

switch on Devel and navigate through the (Object) stdClass which appears under the Devel tab on a node.

Lee